# Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\{en!\}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the limit $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\{en!\}$.

$Attempt:$ $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\{en!\}=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\{(1+{1\over 1!}+{1\over 2!}+{1\over 3!}+...+{1\over n!}+...)n!\}$. The fraction part is what confuses me. Also I don't know if it has something to do with the convergence of $\sum n!$. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: $n!$ goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity, multiplying by $e$ doesn't change that. Are you sure this is what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @Henrik I think that the curly braces around $en!$ mean "fractional part".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write $e = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ so that $$en! =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}$$ so that \begin{align*}\{en!\} &= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots \\ &\le \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} + \cdots \\ &= \frac 1n \end{align*}
where the last equality comes from the geometric series formula. Thus $\{en!\} \to 0$.

Comment: I can't understand how the complete part disappeared...

Comment: What do you mean by "complete part"?

Comment: The floor part...

Comment: That is what we're looking at, isn't it?

Comment: If you have $x = k + \alpha$ where $k \ge 0$ is an integer and $0 < \alpha < 1$ then $\{x\} = \alpha$. The series $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$$ is an integer.

Comment: So that's what I took... Not the fraction part..

Comment: Oh wait. I am sorry, I was mixed up. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose I don't know the last equality. Can't I just see that everything becomes zero?

Comment: What about $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$ ?

Comment: This is not the fractional part... We don't need it

Comment: Nevermind.${}{}{}$