# Problem with inequality and number e

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, factorial, fractions, fractional-part

Prove that, for every positive integer $n$, the following inequality holds:
$$n \{n! \times e\} \lt 1,$$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part function applied to number $x$.

I can;t think of any solution.

Comment: Try expanding out $e$ into the infinite sum and then multiplying by $n!$. The nature of the inequality will change,

Comment: Strongly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123280/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-en.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 
$$e=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+...=$$
$$=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}+...\right)<$$
$$=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+...\right)=$$
$$=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=$$
$$=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}.$$
Thus, $\{en!\}<\frac{1}{n}$ and we are done!