# Need help on limits on greatest integer function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $[x]$ be the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and $\{x\} = x - [x]$. Find the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} n \{n! e\}}$.

Comment: This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1123287/42969

Answer (score 1):

Pulling from [@Umberto P.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67536/umberto-p)'s answer on [Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\{en!\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123280/find-lim-limitsn-to-infty-en/1123287#1123287)

> You can write $e = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ so that
> $$en! =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}$$ so that
> $$\begin{align*} \{ en! \} &= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots \end{align*}$$

Now here we sub in your modification of the problem:

$$
\begin{align*}
n\{n!e\} &= \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} \left( \frac{1}{(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots \right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \cdots \\
&=\{e(n+1)!\} \\
&\to 0
\end{align*}
$$

as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that I have a common factor which is less than 1. Thank you for this one. Appreciate your help on this @jet457

Comment: @Jet457 I think there is a typo in your last equality.